# Android Programming - Facebook Login runtime

Tags: android, facebook

Below is the Fragment Class that contains the facebook login handler. The App crashes everytime it loads with a runtime exception. I have been trying to follow the facebook developer guides but I have a hit a brick wall.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private MainActivity app;
    LoginButton authButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this.getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        app = (MainActivity) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       authButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        return rootView;
    }


    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Here is the log file for the errors. I am  unable to figure out whats causing the runtime error.

```
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): Process: com.example.studygroup, PID: 2565
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studygroup/com.example.studygroup.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.studygroup.MainActivity
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.studygroup.MainActivity
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.example.studygroup.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:32)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5948)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-01 14:55:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.studygroup.MainActivity
```

try this instead:

```
app = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got rid of that line as it wasn't required. The errors were fixed. However, how do I get the "Login with facebook" button to turn into "Logout"

Comment: You can do it in onSessionStateChange, just change the text of the button as you want based on the session state.

Comment: can you give me an example? I am new to this. Do you mean
fb:login_text="Login with Facebook"
        fb:logout_text="Logout" />

Comment: authButton.setText(state.isOpened()?"Logout":"Login with Facebook")